# Java Bytecode Injection

Tags: java, class, edit, code-injection, compiled

Would it be possible to make a Java program which edits a function in a compiled class file by injecting new compiled code into it? Could you just insert the chunk of code as it is into the class?

Comment: Yes, using [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is using AspectJ (http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/starting.html)